# VBA Excel - Range to Array Column contains Time and number, what to convert to string without looping

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table which have various columns, One of which has the Week Number and the other stores a time in hh:mm:ss, I am trying to put both these into an array so I can do a quick comparsion, but I cant work outhow to put them in the array as string so that time would look like "00:10:22" and not its number equivalent 0.3242342342 etc

The week column is dereived from =IFERROR(VALUE([@[DC week]]),"")
and the time column is from =IFERROR(IF(LEFT(P2,1)="-",-TIMEVALUE("00:00"),TIMEVALUE(P2)),"")

This is what I have but the array comes back as double., help please

```
Dim maxtime As String
Dim tblLastRow As Integer
Dim Arr As Variant

Dim uniquesArray As Variant
Dim lastRow As Long

With Sheets("Raw2")
   tblLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

   .Columns("X:X").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=.Range("AE1"), Unique:=True
   lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AE").End(xlUp).row
   uniquesArray = .Range("AE2:AE" & lastRow)

   .Columns("AE").ClearContents


   .Columns("X:Y").Copy
   .Columns("AE").PasteSpecial xlValues


   Arr = .Range("AE2:AF" & tblLastRow)

End With


Sheet20.Columns("A:B").ClearContents
Sheet20.Cells(1, 1) = "Week"
Sheet20.Cells(1, 2) = "Time To Abandon"
For a = 1 To UBound(uniquesArray)
 maxtime = ""
  For i = 1 To UBound(Arr, 1)
    If Arr(i, 1) = uniquesArray(a, 1) Then
      If Arr(i, 2) > maxtime Then maxtime = Arr(i, 2)
    End If
  Next i
  Sheet20.Cells(a + 1, 1) = uniquesArray(a, 1)
  Sheet20.Cells(a + 1, 2) = maxtime   
Next a
```

Comment: Assuming the cells have been formatted how you want them to look within Excel, you should be able to change `Arr = .Range("AE2:AF" & tblLastRow)` to `Arr = .Range("AE2:AF" & tblLastRow).Text`.  Alternatively, you could convert them as you use them using `Format(Arr(i, 2), "hh:mm:ss")`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks YoeE3k, yes the columns are formatted how I want,  I tried Arr = .Range("AE2:AF" & tblLastRow).Text but that returned a null array!  but with using Format(Arr(i, 2), "hh:mm:ss") that worked and because of that I dont need to copy the columns I can just reference the original columns.

```
Dim maxtime As String
Dim tblLastRow As Integer
Dim Arr As Variant

Dim uniquesArray As Variant
Dim lastRow As Long

With Sheets("Raw2")
   tblLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
   .Columns("X:X").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=.Range("AE1"), Unique:=True
   lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AE").End(xlUp).row
   uniquesArray = .Range("AE2:AE" & lastRow)
   .Columns("AE").ClearContents

   Arr = .Range("X2:Y" & tblLastRow)

End With

Sheet20.Columns("A:B").ClearContents
Sheet20.Cells(1, 1) = "Week"
Sheet20.Cells(1, 2) = "Max Time To Abandon"
For a = 1 To UBound(uniquesArray)
 maxtime = ""
  For i = 1 To UBound(Arr, 1)
    If Arr(i, 1) = uniquesArray(a, 1) Then
       If Format(Arr(i, 2), "hh:mm:ss") > maxtime Then maxtime = Format(Arr(i, 2), "hh:mm:ss")

    End If
  Next i
  Sheet20.Cells(a + 1, 1) = uniquesArray(a, 1)
  Sheet20.Cells(a + 1, 2) = maxtime
 Next a
```